# Is it possible to get an sql injection after importing a sql dump?

Tags: sql-injection

Is it possible that after I dump a SQL Database created with prepared statements as an ".sql" file, and then I import it again, that the import may be vulnerable to SQL Injections?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Restoring from an SQL dump *is* an SQL injection.

When you dump a database, you create a script which then executes on your database. This script contains the entire schema, as well as all the data. What you essentially do is tell the database: *"Here is this script, execute everything there."*

If an attacker can modify your SQL dump in any way, then they can insert, remove or modify any part of the database, since their code would essentially run with DB admin privileges upon restore.

Comment: Thanks! I understand the vulnerability that an attacker may modify the dump. But:
without modification: if an attacker inserted a sql injection into the original sql table which was just inserted via the prepared statement. Is it an injection after the dump is imported?

Comment: You cannot "insert an SQL injection into a table". That's not how SQL injections work.

Comment: @TheShmoo - note that if an attacker has been able to create persistence by adding, for example, a trigger on whatever, your import will happily import that trigger that, when fired, restores the attackers ability to connect.

Comment: Thanks for the comments and the answer!
I am creating a separate question where I try to refine my question. I think I did not understand all details yet, but I think this question is answered for this context and I have to get into more detail.